# how to resize UIView with corner handles - similar to 'Pages', 'Keynote'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

I need to add handles (to the corners) of view, so user can resize this view with them. Something similar to edit graphic in Apples 'pages' or 'keynote' apps. (or in any other graphic app).
I did try to add handles subviews to a given view, but those views received touches only in place where both overlapping, inside given view bounds. I need to be able to drag any of the corners handles which will change frame or bounds of that given view. (this part I have already working).

any suggestions, tutorials, links will be appreciated :)

I'm new, so I can't :( post images, so 
[please take a look at link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/handles.png)

Answer (score 2):

I would make a UIGripView that inherits from UIView that is on top of the view you want.

It would:

1. Be given a view to manipulate and size itself accordingly (a little larger, but with the same center)
2. Draw itself (the grips and borders) -- implement `-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect`
3. Register gesture recognizers
4. When a grip is moved, resize the underlying view and yourself accordingly
5. When the center is moved, move the center of the underlying view and yourself.

It might make it easier to deal with gestures if you make each grip a UIView as well, but it's not hard to make some zones in your view and check which one the touch is in.

(Remember to make the touch zones big enough)

Comment: I did try this approach too, but there is another problem with this method. When I add subviews to (let say) resizableView and try to resize it with 'gripview' all subviews messed up. 
examples before and after resizing with 'gripView'
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/beforey.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/afterv.png/

Comment: I wasn't imagining a subView relationship between the grip view and the other view.  I would have them have the same parent and just update the centers and sizes of both in the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    isResizingLR = (self.bounds.size.width - touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && self.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < kResizeThumbSize);
    isResizingUL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
    isResizingUR = (self.bounds.size.width-touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y<kResizeThumbSize);
    isResizingLL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && self.bounds.size.height -touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
 }

 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previous=[[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:self];

    float  deltaWidth = touchPoint.x-previous.x;
    float  deltaHeight = touchPoint.y-previous.y;

    if (isResizingLR) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y,touchPoint.x + deltaWidth, touchPoint.y + deltaWidth);
    }  
    if (isResizingUL) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth, self.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight, self.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, self.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);
    } 
    if (isResizingUR) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x ,self.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  self.frame.size.width + deltaWidth, self.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);      
    } 
    if (isResizingLL) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth ,self.frame.origin.y ,  self.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, self.frame.size.height + deltaHeight);   
    }

    if (!isResizingUL && !isResizingLR && !isResizingUR && !isResizingLL) {
        self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + touchPoint.x - touchStart.x,self.center.y + touchPoint.y - touchStart.y);
    }
}
```